# TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined

Tags: react-native, helper, back

I am using RN and would like to go back to the previous screen, but the debugging show: "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\DGar\DGar\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:179 TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined". How can I do right now? Please help me!

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
Alert,
Dimensions,
ScrollView,
TextInput,
TouchableOpacity,
BackHandler,
} from 'react-native';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Image } from 'react-native';

```
const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('screen').width;
const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('screen').height;
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';
import { NavigationUtils } from '../../navigations';
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';

export default class RecentReport extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    Navigation.events().bindComponent(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress());
  }

  navigationButtonPressed({ buttonId }) {
    switch (buttonId) {
      case 'backPress': {
        this.handleBackPress();
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  handleBackPress = (props) => {
    props.navigation.goBack(null);
    return true;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Hi</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

RecentReport.options = {
  topBar: {
    animate: true,
    elevation: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Warning',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      alignment: 'center',
    },
    leftButtons: [
      {
        id: 'backButton',
        icon: require('../../assets/icons/back-button.png'),
        color: '#5B7C56',
      },
    ],
  },
  statusBar: {
    backgroundColor: '#5B7C56',
  },
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  imageItem: {
    height: screenHeight / 4,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#5B7C56',
    borderRadius: 20,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  warningContainer: {
    padding: 10,
  },
  spacingBetween: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  spacing: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  contentContainer: {
    padding: 10,
  },
  addWarningButton: {
    height: 70,
    width: 70,
    borderRadius: 50,
    borderColor: 'black',
    backgroundColor: '#5B7C56',
    borderWidth: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    marginRight: 13,
    marginTop: 13,
  },
});
```

Comment: Have you declared your current screen under Stack.Navigator?

Comment: Hi Rohit, Here is my code: https://www.codepile.net/pile/0PmdQa9A . I am using react-native-navigation. Is this work?

Comment: could you help me @Rohit, maybe through TeamViewer, it wil be so precious if I have that honor

Comment: Hi @Nguyễn Mạnh I will surely look at your code and sorry will not be able to connect through TeamViewer.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Do yo have any suggestion or feedback for me, please reply in this question to me know? Thank you so much

Comment: You have created the stack in some different manner as I have seen and done. [https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator] Refer this for creating stack. And can you please share GitHub link for the project .I would love to fix errors.